# I'm trying to integrate cobra in my program

Tags: go

I was referring to [spf13/cobra](https://github.com/spf13/cobra).

I downloaded the cobra package using  `go get github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra` and imported `"github.com/spf13/cobra"` in my program and then installed it using  `go install github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra`.

This is my program - It is a calculator which can be implemented of number of inputs , but for now only 2 are taken from the user. I wanted to use cobra in this program.

```
    package main

    import (
                "fmt"
                "github.com/spf13/cobra"
            )


    func add(m ...int) int {
        sum := 0
        for _, a := range m {
            sum += a
        }
        return sum
    }
    func sub(m ...int) int {
        sub := m[0]
        for _, a := range m[1:] {
            sub -= a
        }
        return sub
    }
    func mul(m ...float32) float32 {
        pro := float32(1)
        for _, a := range m {
            pro *= a
        }
        return pro
    }
    func div(m ...float32) float32 {
        quo := m[0]
        for _, a := range m[1:] {
            quo /= a
        }
        return quo
    }

    var i int

    func display() {

        fmt.Println("Choose the operation : 1:Addition 2:Subtration 3:Multiplication 4:Division ")
        fmt.Scanln(&i)
    }

    func main() {

        display()

        var v1,v2 int
        fmt.Println("Enter 2 numbers with enter")
        fmt.Scanln(&v1)
        fmt.Scanln(&v2)

        switch i {
        case 1:
            fmt.Println(add(v1,v2))
        case 2:
            fmt.Println(sub(v1,v2))
        case 3:
            fmt.Println(mul(float32(v1),float32(v2)))
        case 4:
      fmt.Println(div(float32(v1),float32(v2))) 
         }
    }
```

Comment: Did you run go get ? `go get github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra`

Comment: Do you have git client installed?

Comment: Run `go install github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra` and make sure you have `$GOPATH/bin` in your `PATH`.

Comment: @John S Perayil   Yes, I did

Comment: @codinggirl Can you give more details in your question ? Include everything you are doing related to `cobra`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `go get github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra` first. `go install` can only install packages you've already downloaded, `go get` downloads *and* installs a package.

Comment: I did run go get -v github.com/spf13/cobra/cobra